# Q: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, fasttext

I am using `FastText.load_fasttext_format()`to load fastText Offial Japanese trained model(300 dim) in Google Colab.
Here is my code.

```
model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/IDR/rakuten/wikipedia_fastText/cc.ja.300.bin"
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format(model_path)
```

And here is the encoding error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-61d7c85f09b2> in <module>()
      2 
      3 model_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/IDR/rakuten/wikipedia_fastText/cc.ja.300.bin"
----> 4 model = FastText.load_fasttext_format(model_path)

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/fasttext.py in _load_dict(self, file_handle, encoding)
    818                 word_bytes += char_byte
    819                 char_byte = file_handle.read(1)
--> 820             word = word_bytes.decode(encoding)
    821             count, _ = self.struct_unpack(file_handle, '@qb')
    822 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error seems to be `unexpected end of data`.

Are you sure the `cc.ja.300.bin` file you've downloaded is the full untruncated length, and uncorrupted contents to match any declared checksum, from the source where it was downloaded?

Separately, the `load_fasttext_format()` class method is [deprecated in current versions of Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.FastText.load_fasttext_format), with [`load_facebook_model()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model) now the preferred form (though this wouldn't account for your error).